# action on the maximal torus

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, group-actions, algebraic-groups

For the algebraic group $PGL_4(K)$ where $K$ is algebraically closed with char not eq $2$, we have an elementary abelian $2-$subgroup

$$E = \left<\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}\right>.$$

I can obtain myself $C_G(E)^{\circ} = T_3$ ($3$-dim torus) and I obtained the info that $C_G(E)/C_G(E)^{\circ} \cong V_4$ (the Klein $4$ group) by direct computing. What is the action of this $V_4$ on $T_3$? Do the non-identity elements act by inverting the three tori?

Comment: What's the circle mean?

Comment: It's the connected component of $C$.